# Automatic audio segmentation and find the most energetic segments

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, sound, audio

What algorithm can be used for audio segmentation? I want to divide song to segments and find the most energetic segments (*begin and end in seconds*). It is needed for the rhythm-game.

**Examples**:

https://soundcloud.com/dieantwoord-yolandi/die-antwoord-cookie-thumper
(most energetic segments: *first 3:09-3:38; second 5:02-5:27*)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StZcUAPRRac (rammstein - sonne)
(most energetic segments: *first 0:55-1:20; second 1:52-2:44*)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an answer for this one.

You first load the audio data to an [AudioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) of course. Then you sample the data from that clip into an array.

```
AudioSource aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
float[] samples = new float[aud.clip.samples * aud.clip.channels];
aud.clip.GetData(samples, 0);
```

Now, you have your data in hand. What you want to find out is the different segments of songs. So, I suggest (because this part can be done in numerous ways) going through the clip, X samples at a time, and getting the mean value of those samples.

Since samples vary between -1.0F and 1.0F, you do need to get rid of the negative values (or the positive whichever you prefer) for this method to be of any value.

```
int X = Y; //Y is the number of samples you want to consider, X is any name you want
int checkNum = samples.Length/X; //because we don't want this to be done a lot of times
float[] sampleMeans = new float[checkNum];
float currentMean = 0;
int j, i;
for (j = 0; j < checkNum; j++)
    {
    currentMean = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
         if(samples[i+j*X]==null) //check whether the value is null 
             {break;} //and insure we don't go past the array
         if(samples[i+j*X]>=0) //make sure values are positive or taking a mean will not mean much (get it?)
             {currentMean = currentMean + samples[i+j*X];}
        }
    sampleMeans[j] = currentMean / i;
    }
```

After this is all done, you will have an array that represents the means of every X samples. You can check this array to see whether that part is more energetic.

For example if `sampleMeans[2]` is bigger than 0.5F, then you can say that the third X samples are energetic and start from `samples[3*X]` and iterate to `samples[4*X-1]` adding each element into a new array.

If the next part also suits your conditions, then add that part into the array you just made, if not, then make the last one into a new `AudioClip` by using `SetData` method. Then repeat the process with this new data set. (It's going to take some thinking, but it's all essentially gruntwork.)